# Missing text on Unix Main site

Tags: support

On questions without answers, I noticed that the text at the bottom looks like this "Share a link to this question via email, Google+, , or .". There is a word missing before the comma to the left of the word "or". Also, there is a word missing after the word "or". Is a developer in the process of changing that text?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a browser add-on

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I set Adsblock Plus to block anything related to Facebook and Twitter.

[image: Missing text]

Answer (score 2):

Looks OK to me...

[image: Screenshot of social links]

Comment: It will look fine for you. I figured it out. View my answer @jasonwryan.